# If the coefficient matrix of a linear system of 4 equations in 4 variables has pivot position every row, is it consistent?

Tags: linear-algebra

Title basically explains everything but I'll just restate it to make everything more clear. 
If the coefficient matrix of a linear system of four equations in four variables has a pivot position in every row, is the system consistent? If it is consistent, how many solutions does it have? 
I don't even know where to start from and I'd really appreciate if you can help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that by consistent you mean that it has at least one solution, then yes, having a pivot in every row (and thus column) does imply that it is consistent. In addition we can say that the solution must be unique because there are no free variables in the system. In order to see hwy this is true, I recommend writing down a matrix with a pivot in every column and then "translating" that to a statement about a system of four equations in four variables. Think about what that might imply about your solution space.